# preloading jquery ui icons - is there a trick?

Tags: jquery-ui, image-preloader

What's the best way to get the jquery ui icons to preload for rollover/hover etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '/themes/yourTheme/images/ui-icons_whatever.png';
```

Note that this is done asynchronously, so the rest of the page may load before the image(s) finish loading- but at least they will (probably) load before the user triggers a hover or other event.